# ADO ACE OLEDB 12.0 Excel Front end with VBA troubleshooting

Tags: excel, oledb, ado, adodb, vba

I am using Excel 2013 as a front end application written w/ VBA.
I've linked a XLSX file inside an Access 2013 database in order to use SQL simply for example to read MAX Value of a column of which datas are filtered with a Where Clause.
I cannot understand why a SQL statement for retrieving MAX value does not work whereas the same statement is OK via SQL Querying in Access.

Hereafter VBA code excerpt :

```
varCnxStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & 
G_sWBookREINVOICingFilePath & ";Mode="

With conXLdb
  '*
  '.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
  '.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & G_sWBookREINVOICingFilePath & ";"     
  & "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR = YES'"
  '.Mode = adModeShareExclusive
  .Open varCnxStr & adModeShareExclusive
  '*
End With

Debug.Print varCnxStr & adModeShareExclusive

strSQL = "SELECT MAX(InvoiceNum) as LastNumInvoice"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM ReInvoiceDB "
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE InvoiceNum > " & strYMPrefix_p & "000"
strSQL = strSQL & ";"

Debug.Print strSQL

adoXLrst.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=conXLdb,   
CursorType:=adOpenStatic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, Options:=adCmdText
adoXLrst.MoveFirst

'Set adoXLrst = conXLdb.Execute(strSQL)
HighestStr = adoXLrst![LastNumInvoice]

 adoXLrst.Close

 strGSFNumber = HighestStr '>> byref returning value 

conXLdb.Close

Veloma:

  '>>
  On Error Resume Next
 Set adoXLrst = Nothing
 Set conXLdb = Nothing
 Exit Sub
'>>

Diso:
   Beep
   Beep
  '>>
  strGSFNumber = "ERR"
  '>>
  sMsg = "pG_getNEXTInvoiceValueXLasDB-ERR ::" & Err.Number & ":: - " &
  Err.Description

 MsgBox sMsg, vbOKOnly + vbCritical
 sRet = sMsg
 Resume Veloma
End Sub
```

It returns Null value in variable HighestStr whereas it should receive a double value ...

Any help or any clue on misfunctionning ? 
Regards.

Comment: I ve imported datas into table and changed Provider subsequently, it returns 0 recordcount as if the table is not fetched. I'm wondering if the database Access is open. No change on modified time for the Accdb file.
How to be sure tha OLEDB is functionning ? 
The error tracking module is working fine indicating EOF BOF are both true...

Comment: It is necessary to describe  "group by"  statement

Comment: I've made some search : ADO is not that adequat with Access database. I'v changed for Microsoft Office Access engine libraries reference in my Excel workbook and the SQL query is OK now.

This is a good solution I think.